# php extended class connect mysql issue

Tags: php, mysql

I have three files:

- config.php
- dbsng.php
- bookclass.php

***bookclass.php***:

```
include 'config.php';
include 'dbsngt.php';

/**
* Books
*/
class Books extends Database
{

public $db;
protected $title;
protected $id;
protected $code;

function __construct()
{
$this->db = self::obtain(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE);
if ($this->db->connect()){echo "YES connected";} else {echo "No connection";}

}

}
```

***dbsngt.php:***

```
class Database{

// debug flag for showing error messages
public  $debug = true;

// Store the single instance of Database
private static $instance;

private $server   = ""; //database server
private $user     = ""; //database login name
private $pass     = ""; //database login password
private $database = ""; //database name

private $error = "";

#######################
//number of rows affected by SQL query
public  $affected_rows = 0;

private $link_id = 0;
private $query_id = 0;


#-#############################################
# desc: constructor
private function __construct($server=null, $user=null, $pass=null, $database=null){
// error catching if not passed in
if($server==null || $user==null || $database==null){
    $this->oops("Database information must be passed in when the object is first created.");
}

$this->server=$server;
$this->user=$user;
$this->pass=$pass;
$this->database=$database;
}#-#constructor()


#-#############################################
# desc: singleton declaration
public static function obtain($server=null, $user=null, $pass=null, $database=null){
if (!self::$instance){ 
    self::$instance = new Database($server, $user, $pass, $database); 
} 

return self::$instance; 
}#-#obtain()


#-#############################################
# desc: connect and select database using vars above
# Param: $new_link can force connect() to open a new link, even if mysql_connect() was called before with the same parameters
public function connect($new_link=false){
$this->link_id=@mysql_connect($this->server,$this->user,$this->pass,$new_link);

if (!$this->link_id){//open failed
    $this->oops("Could not connect to server: <b>$this->server</b>.");
    }

if(!@mysql_select_db($this->database, $this->link_id)){//no database
    $this->oops("Could not open database: <b>$this->database</b>.");
    }

// unset the data so it can't be dumped
$this->server='';
$this->user='';
$this->pass='';
$this->database='';
}


}
```

When I execute the following code,it says ***No connection*** 
I have inherited the Database class even after I cant make the connection

```
include 'classes/bookclass.php';
$obj = new Books();
```

Comment: That's the wrong OOP hierarchy. *Is* your `Books` a `Database`? Would you use an instance of `Books` *in place of* an instance of `Database`? No, you wouldn't. What you want is to inject an instance of `Database` to the constructor of `Books`. Composition, not inheritance.

Comment: change the private access for the database connection variable to public
                public $server   = ""; //database server
                public $user     = ""; //database login name
                Public $pass     = ""; //database login password
                public $database = ""; //database name

Comment: Actually I want to have an access to all methods and fields of Database class extending it to my Book class. In Database class there are more methods then I've shown.

Comment: I've tried change all of this to public. Bot still "No connections"

Comment: refere http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: Can u please show the content of `config.php`? where probably you have defined these constants DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE..

Comment: Yes ...
define('DB_SERVER', "10.10.4.3");

//database login name
define('DB_USER', "test");
//database login password
define('DB_PASS', "pass+++");

//database name
define('DB_DATABASE', "books");

Comment: I've even changed private to public in Database class some variables. But doesn't work. Config file is right. I thought that extending Database class and connecting in _construct I'll get all methods of Database class.

Comment: I don't know what I've done but it works now.

When I check it writing:

    if ($this->db->connect()){echo "YES connected";} else {echo "No connection";}
it tells me No connection, but if I use simply

    $this->db->connect(); //whithout checking
it works well.

That means when I use IF... it doesn't connect before checking.

Anyway. Thank you very much.

***IT IS SOLVED!!!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the private access for the database connection variable to public

```
public $server   = ""; //database server
public $user     = ""; //database login name
public $pass     = ""; //database login password
public $database = ""; //database name
```